Use Blender in tandem with a Digital Audio Workstation
How can I integrate Blender with a DAW and synchronize?
I'd like to sync transport and exchange MIDI messages, sort of remote controlling each other.
I'd like this to be software agnostic.
Now, I guess Jack could be a solution, even if I had troubles with it and Windows in the Past.
I had some luck with Linux + Jack + Wine (FL Studio).
Another possible solution could be using Asio drivers, Blender and Jack somehow works with this.
But since I had limited results, I'd like to know from experts instead.
Thanks in advance for any help, regards, have a nice day.
